# One button on the page will not call the code behind, other buttons work

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

Every button on the page works except for one.  When it is clicked, it displays the confirmation box.  When it is confirmed true, it does nothing.  The other buttons work on the page so I am not sure why the code behind is not getting called.

**UPDATE:** I need to have a confirmation that the person wanted to push the button and that is why I have the "onclientclick" attribute.

This is the button that does NOT work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeclineServices" runat="server" Text="Purge Scanned Image" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  CssClass="redinput" TabIndex="-1" OnClientClick="return confirmDeclineServices();" OnClick="btnDeclineServices_Click" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
```

This is the Code behind that is called:

```
protected void btnDeclineServices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

This is the Javascript function for onclientclick:

```
function confirmDeclineServices() {
if (confirm('Are you sure you want this flyer set to Declined Services?')) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

When I Push the button, it displays the confirmation dialog, when I push OK, it does nothing.

It is very confusing because this button placed right next to it does work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEnterFlyerData" runat="server" Text="Enter Flyer Data" UseSubmitBehavior="false" TabIndex="201" OnClick="btnEnterFlyerData_Click" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: WHat should happen on ok? The snippet of "code behind that is called" is not enough to know why it's not working as expected. Also, any stacktrace?

Comment: Client call runs first and probably preventing from reaching the server side method. Try removing OnClientClient handler to see if it works first. Then go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple and quick fix as explained below.

You need to change the ClientClick value to what's given below. I am assuming that when the `confirmDeclineServices` method returns a false then you do not want to execute the code-behind.

So if user confirms as yes, then you let the normal processing carry on in ASP.Net. Right now you are always returning from the client click method that then stops all ASP.Net client-side processing that was hooked up with this button.

```
OnClientClick="var go = confirmDeclineServices(); if(go === false) { return false;}"
```

When the regular ASP.Net processing takes over on the client-side, only then is the page posted back and code-behind executed. By using a `return` statement you are stopping this process.  So only use `return` value when you want the button to not post back.

**UPDATE 1**

Let me explain in more detail.

Let's say you have an asp button with markup as below. It will finally render in your browser with the html in second code snippet below. The ASP.Net client-side processing that I am talking about is the call of this method `__doPostBack('btn1','')` which ASP.Net executes after `clientclick` code is executed.

So, if you return in `clientclick` then the ASP.Net method does not execute and no post back occurs.

*ASP.Net Button Markup*

```
   <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text ="Button1"
    UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="var x =1;"  OnClick="btn1_Click"/>
```

*ASP.Net Button Rendered Html*

```
<input type="button" name="btn1" value="Button1"
    onclick="var x =1;__doPostBack('btn1','')" id="btn1">
```

If you set `UseSubmitBehavior` to true then your original code should have worked, but you are using `UseSubmitBehavior = false` it seems. So changing this property could be another option for you, but if not then just use the original fix I have provided.

Comment: Thank you So Much!!!!  I am not sure what the difference is though.  Why did adding the variable Go make it work? What is the difference between that and just returning true from the javascript function?

Comment: I added `go` just so you could understand it more clearly. You could as well have used this:`if (confirmDeclineServices() === false) { return false; }`

Comment: Also, like I said you should only use a return statement if you want to stop ASP.Net from posting back the page.

Comment: When confirm = true, instead of returning true, do nothing.

Comment: In ASP.Net the way `clientclick` is handled is that it executes before the standard JavaScript from ASP.Net gets executed. Now if you return  in `clientclick` then the JavaScript from ASP.Net will never execute.

Comment: Yes, jordan is correct. If you return true or return false, you are basically stopping any further processing by ASP.Net.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your first button has OnClientClick="return confirmDeclineServices();", which should run some script on the client browser. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx) that attribute also co opts the standard OnClick event as well.